# how to select data from with in a query for calculation

Tags: sql

My table has thousand rows and two main columns (`invoice_no`, `exe_amount`) and I want to write following query:

```
select invoice_ no, 
       exe_amount, 
       exe_amount*0.02 as edu_duty, 
       exe_amount*0.01 as ed_duty, 
       (exe_amount + edu_duty + ed_duty) as sub_total, 
       subtotal*0.0605 as st_amount, 
       sub_total*.0103 as ot_amount,
       exe_amount + subtotal + st_amount + ot_amount as gd_amount 
from table1;
```

If I approach it with variables query gives error of multiple values .

How do I approach this? Aany tutorial link for solving problem?

Comment: What is your dbms?mysql?sqlserver?oracle?

Comment: What's wrong with that query? What is the error you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use alias while calculation

```
select invoice_ no, 
       exe_amount, 
       exe_amount*0.02 as edu_duty, 
       exe_amount*0.01 as ed_duty, 
      (exe_amount + (exe_amount*0.02) + (exe_amount*0.01)) as sub_total, 
      ((exe_amount + (exe_amount*0.02) + (exe_amount*0.01)))*0.0605 as st_amount, 
      (exe_amount + (exe_amount*0.02) + (exe_amount*0.01)) *.0103 as ot_amount,
      ( exe_amount + 
        (exe_amount + (exe_amount*0.02) + (exe_amount*0.01)) + 
        ((exe_amount + (exe_amount*0.02) + (exe_amount*0.01)))*0.0605 + (exe_amount + (exe_amount*0.02) + (exe_amount*0.01)) *.0103 
      ) as gd_amount 
from table1;
```

Alter Native to above one is

```
SELECT invoice_ no,
       exe_amount,
       edu_duty ,
       ed_duty,
       sub_total,
       subtotal*0.0605 as st_amount, 
       sub_total*.0103 as ot_amount,
       exe_amount + subtotal + (subtotal*0.0605) + (sub_total*.0103) as gd_amount
FROM (
        select invoice_ no, 
               exe_amount, 
               exe_amount*0.02 as edu_duty, 
               exe_amount*0.01 as ed_duty, 
              (exe_amount + (exe_amount*0.02) + (exe_amount*0.01)) as sub_total
       from tableName
)t
```